# How do I set element to display where my mouse clicks? (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have some code below which shows/hides an `li` element when I click on an image. The code below works as intended; however, the image I'm using fits the entire screen and currently when the `li` element is shown it displays on the very top left of the image. I want the `li` element to display exactly where I'm clicking but having difficulty figuring out how I can do that. Please advice.

**GamePage.js**

```
const GamePage = () => {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsShown((current) => !current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="gamepage" onClick={handleClick}>
      {isShown && (
        <ul className="menu">
          <li className="menu-item">Waldo</li>
        </ul>
      )}
      <GamePageImage />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**GamePage.css**

```
.gamepage {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;

  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;

  border: 1px solid #3e3e3e;
  width: 100px;
}

.menu > li {
  margin: 0;

  color: white;
  background-color: #3e3e3e;
}

.menu > li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onClick` fires an event, where you can get the `x` and `y` coordinates.
Save that position and use it on your `ul` element to place it where you want it.
I've added some CSS to `ul` which will place it exactly where you click.

```js
const GamePage = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([0,0]) // State to save the position where you clicked

const  handleClick = (event) => {
        setIsVisible(current => !current)
        setPosition([event.pageX,event.pageY]) // Save the pos where you clicked
    } 

  return (
    <div className="gamepage" onClick={handleClick}>
      {isVisible&& (
        <ul className="menu" style={{
        position: "absolute",
        left: position[0],
        top: position[1],
        tranform: "translateX(-50%)",
        transform: "translateY(-50%)",
        }}>
          <li className="menu-item">Waldo</li>
        </ul>
      )}
      <GamePageImage />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer. One problem I have noticed is I'm using a pretty large image on the main page. When I scroll down a bit the `li` doesn't show up where I click and instead shows up towards the top of the page. I'll keep messing around trying to remedy but any ideas for a fix?

Comment: Is it only the Y coordinate who is incorrect? Does x place itself accurate? I assume this happens when the image is so big that you have to scroll?

Comment: yeah it's when I have to scroll [here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/NoJPrZu.png) of what I mean. If you can't see it then it seems to be the `left` working fine but the `top` isn't going down.  My code for the image is just a simple `img` tag.

Comment: Updated my answer. Now using event.pageX and event.pageY instead of clientX and clientY. This will give you coordinates relative to the whole document instead of the viewport window